# How to remove Quote Marks From Product Name

Tags: magento-1.9, php, data, layer

I'm need to remove the quote marks from the product name because it is messing up the Data Layer.

```
$product['name'] = $item->getName();
```

How can I do it in the above code? Thanks

Comment: Does that mean your product names are like this `'name'` ?

Comment: No some my product names have quote marks in them, for example,  Natures Grace "Grace" Figurine. And I get errors: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$product['name'] = str_replace('"', '', $item->getName()); // This will remove all double quotes from product name.
```

Comment: How could I add that to the above code? It seems I remember Magento having some kind of code for this. Not sure.

Comment: Updated the code. Check now.

Comment: If the answer helps kindly try to accept it.

Comment: I think it will work, but I might have the wrong place targeted. : ) Be back